# Split List Elements in byte format to separate bytes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list with byte elements like this:

```
list = [b'\x00\xcc\n', b'\x14I\x8dy_\xeb\xbc1C']
```

Now I want to separate all bytes like following:

```
list_new =[b'\x00', b'\xcc', b'\x14I', b'\x8dy_', b'\xeb', b'\xbc1C']
```

Comment: What's the logic here? Why not split `b'\x14I'` like `[b'\x14', b'I']`? And `b'\x8dy_'` like `[b'\x8d', b'y', b'_']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming here that you wanted to split the data with split criteria of '\x', this seems to be matching with your desired output. Let me know otherwise. Also I am not sure why you got this type of string, its little awkward to work with. A bigger context on the question might be more helpful. Nevertheless, I tried to get your desired output in following way:(May be not efficient but gets your job done).

```
import re
from codecs import encode

lists = [b'\x00\xcc\n', b'\x14I\x8dy_\xeb\xbc1C']

split = [re.split(r'(?=\\x)', str(item)) for item in lists] ## splitting with assumption of \x using lookarounds here

output = [] ## container to save the final item
for item in split: ## split is list of lists hence required two for loops
    for nitem in item:
        if nitem != "b'": ## remove anything which has only "b'"
            output.append(nitem.replace('\\n','').replace("'",'').encode()) ## finally appending everyitem
            ## Note here that output contains two backward slashes , to remove them we use encode function from codecs module
            ## like below

[encode(itm.decode('unicode_escape'), 'raw_unicode_escape') for itm in output] ## Final output
```

**Output:**

```
[b'\x00', b'\xcc', b'\x14I', b'\x8dy_', b'\xeb', b'\xbc1C']
```

Comment: Hi @PKumar you are right i want to split with every \x. I got this string from reading a file. The code work in the python console but not in my script. When i compile it i get following error: split() requires a non-emty pattern match. Can you help me here?

Comment: @Flu, I am not sure what could be the problem, I run it via python command line, this works for me. Are you running some more examples apart from what you shown here in the example?

Comment: I had wrong python version running. Thank you for your help